# Table-styled elements do not show IE gradients correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, linear-gradients

I've run across a peculiarity with IE8/9 regarding its Gradient filter. Consider the following styles:

```
background:#F2F2F2;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#F2F2F2,#CECECE);
background:   -moz-linear-gradient(top,#F2F2F2,#CECECE);
background:     -o-linear-gradient(top,#F2F2F2,#CECECE);
background:  linear-gradient(to bottom,#F2F2F2,#CECECE);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(startColorStr='#F2F2F2',endColorStr='#CECECE',GradientType=0)";
```

The gradients display correctly on elements with `display:block;`. However when applied to `display:table;` IE9 will display `#F2F2F2` on top of the gradient. To fix this temporarily, I've removed the background-color, but of course now I don't have a solid color fallback.

My question is: why is it doing this and what are the (no-js) workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` gradients have a number of major limitations and bugs. It looks like you've discovered one of them.

If your base-level for browser support is IE9, then you might want to look into using an SVG data-url for the gradient. This is a fairly common work-around for gradients in IE9. Although it can make your code messy and diffiult to work with, it does at least work well.

You can generate an SVG gradient data-url from here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/SVGGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html

If you need to support IE8 or earlier, this won't work, and frankly I don't think you're going to find any other non-js solution that will satisfy you. (other than going back to the old-skool and using PNG image for the background gradient)

The only good solution I know of that works for all IE versions is to use the [CSS3Pie library](http://www.css3pie.com/). Yes, this is a JS lib, so it doesn't meet your non-js criteria, but it's pretty unintrusive (other browsers will ignore it entirely and not even download it). It also has the advantage of allowing you to use standards-based code for your gradients even in really old IE versions. You can still provide a solid colour fall-back for those users who do have JS disabled, so your site should work for everyone to some level or another.

Comment: I assumed as much. That seems like such a random glitch. But what part of IE8 is _not_ plagued with **random** glitches?

IE8 still haunts us as most of our users continue to log in from schools or workplaces that haven't upgraded to even 9 (come on people!!!). I didn't know that CSS3PIE doesn't download on non-IE browsers. I'm sure if the boss gripes about it I'll end up going that route. For now, defaulting to flat background doesn't ruffle too many feathers. --Thanks much!